# How to write a unittest for importing a module in Python

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

What is the pythonic way of writing a unittest to see if a module is properly installed? By properly installed I mean, it does not raise an ImportError: No module named foo.

Comment: Generally, there's not a lot to unit test.  Do you not trust the `import` statement?  The import line of code is so simple -- and so easy to inspect -- that it seems a bit silly to unit test it.  Why are you unit testing the `import` statement?

Comment: As I have to deploy my Django application on a different server and it requires some extra modules I want to make sure that all required modules are installed. For example, making sure that simplejson is installed for python 2.5. Of course I trust the import statement, I just don't want to forget installing a module I need.

Comment: Seems like You're running tests on production environment, which is...strange. Anyway, you're testing that you have proper dependencies, which is a job for package manager. Either create packages for your application, or use pythonic dependency managers (pip and pip install -r requirements.txt in virtualenv comes to mind).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As I have to deploy my Django
>   application on a different server and
>   it requires some extra modules I want
>   to make sure that all required modules
>   are installed.

This is not a unit test scenario at all.

This is a production readiness process and it isn't -- technically -- a test of your application.

It's a query about the environment.  Ours includes dozens of things.

Start with a simple script like this.  Add each thing you need to be sure exists.

```
try:
    import simplejson
except ImportError:
    print "***FAILURE: simplejson missing***"
    sys.exit( 2 )
sys.exit( 0 )
```

Just run this script in each environment as part of installation.  It's not a unit test at all.  It's a precondition for setup install.

Comment: Thanks so much, and sorry for using the wrong terminology, it obviously put a whole bunch of people on the wrong foot :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you'd need to test this, but something like:

```
def my_import_test(self):
    import my_module
```

If an import error is raised the test has failed, if not it passes.

Comment: Maybe I am not clear in what I need. I want to test whether the import of a module is successful or not so I can see what modules are missing and need to be installed. So how can I use an self.assertUnequals... statement